# CollegeScoreCard - Earnings from 2012 for 2014 query

Tags: collegescorecard

Why is the earnings data taken from 2012 whereas other fields are all from 2014?

https://github.com/RTICWDT/college-scorecard/blob/dev/js/src/picc.js#L492

> MEDIAN_EARNINGS:      '2012.earnings.10_yrs_after_entry.median',

Also the data for 2013 and 2014 are null for all records (I verified many schools).

Comment: can you clean this up? specifically, pointing to the canonical source of the data, and if those issues lie therein? also, i'm assuming you meant many, not may. why you felt the need to point out penn is beyond me. how did you verify? what methods have you done?

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of Scorecard, the most recent median earnings data describe earnings in the 2012 and 2013 calendar years. As such, any median earning values in datafiles describing a later time are assigned a NULL. For more details, see the cohort_map in the data dictionary: https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/assets/CollegeScorecardDataDictionary.xlsx